# Powershell Regex match for string between brackets

Tags: regex, powershell, brackets

I got stuck here...
I need a powershell script to monitor log rotation looking for some strings inside the file. The Scripts works perfectly until here, but without regex: (log.txt).

The format I need to match the filenames are like this:

```
Service_ITOPS_Log[2021-08-15].txt
```

Until now I tried to do it like this directly on the filename:

`$path = 'Desktop\ProbeService_ITOPS_Log\[\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}].txt'`

``` $path = 'Desktop\ProbeService_ITOPS_Log``[2021-08-15``].txt' ``` <<-- This works escaping the brackets, but without Regex for sure.

And tried with the Get-ChildItem:

```
$file= Get-ChildItem -Path $folder | Where-Object { $_.Name -match 'Service_ITOPS_Log\[\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}].txt'}


The error is that it doesn't find the file, but for troubleshooting purposes it prints the path correctly.
```

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69000882/edit) the error message into your existing post :)

Comment: Try with `-LiteralPath` instead of `-Path`. I would also add `-Filter 'Service_ITOPS_Log*.txt' -File`

Comment: Whats `$folder`, should that be `$path`? `Get-ChildItem` should look something like this `Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Logs" | Where-Object { $_.Name -match 'Service_ITOPS_Log\[\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\].txt'}`